# OpenPyXL を使って xlsx ファイル中の文字列を複数条件でまとめて置換したい

Tags: python, python3, openpyxl

xlsxに含まれる「a-i－u」などの文字列から半角・全角ハイフンをなくすため置換を行いたいです。
下記のように複数条件を入れるとエラーになってしまうのですが、複数条件でまとめて置換する方法はありますでしょうか。

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('book.xlsx')
ws = wb.worksheets[0]

if os.listdir('ファイルがあるフォルダー'):
    for i in range(ws.max_row):
        for row in ws.iter_rows():
                for cell in row:
　　　　　　　　　　　#6は置換したい文字列が存在する列
                    if cell.col_idx == 6:
　　　　　　　　　　　　　#置換部分
                        text = cell.value.replace(["-","－"], "")
                        cell.value = text
```

・エラーコード

```
text = cell.value.replace(["-","－"], "")
TypeError: replace() argument 1 must be str, not list
```

置換箇所をtext2などで複数回に分けて処理することができるのであればその方法でも問題ありません。

Comment: 参考として `text = ''.join(x for x in cell.value if x not in u'-－')` という様な方法もあります。

Answer (score 2):

置換(削除)する部分を`re`モジュールで行えば良いのでは？
[Pythonで複数の文字列を削除したい ー re.subを使う](https://qiita.com/kenTee/items/dcf63aa2895122bb3fd1#resub%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%86)

`import re`しておけば、このように出来るでしょう。

```
text = re.sub(r"[-－]", "", cell.value)
cell.value = text
```

Comment: 解決できました！
ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1):

[translate](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate)による一括置換方法もあります。
参考: [Pythonで文字列を置換（replace, translate, re.sub, re.subn）](https://note.nkmk.me/python-str-replace-translate-re-sub/)

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Book1.xlsx')
ws = wb.worksheets[0]
hyphens = ["-", "－"]
trans = str.maketrans({"-": "", "－": ""})

for r in range(ws.max_row):
    #6は置換したい文字列が存在する列
    cell = ws.cell(row=r+1, column=6)
    if cell.value != None:
        #置換部分
        cell.value = cell.value.translate(trans)

#上書き保存
wb.save('Book1.xlsx')
```

Comment: 別の方法もご教示いただきありがとうございます！
覚えておくようにします！